# 'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, installation

I already used Rails on my machine, but I decided to reinstall it because the gems were acting up because of a special character in my home directory where the gem repository used to be.

So I uninstalled ruby using rubyinstaller's uninstaller, deleted all my gem folders, rubygems etc etc.

Now I set my GEM_HOME path to c:\GemRepository, reinstalled ruby and rubygems and devkit. when I run gem install rails, I get this:

```
Successfully installed rails-3.1.3
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.3...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.3...
file 'lib' not found
```

If i try to run rails, it says "'rails' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

I also tried installing with the -include-dependencies flag, but then I get

```
Fetching: multi_json-1.0.4.gem (100%)
Fetching: rails-3.1.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.0.4
Successfully installed rails-3.1.3
2 gems installed
Installing ri documentation for multi_json-1.0.4...
Installing ri documentation for rails-3.1.3...
file 'lib' not found
Installing RDoc documentation for multi_json-1.0.4...
Installing RDoc documentation for rails-3.1.3...
file 'lib' not found
```

And again, rails is not recognized as a command. Please, please, help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I figured out that the root of the problem was that the 'home' folder in Windows is  in a path that contains my user name, and my user name happens to contain the special character 'á' (Zoltán).

After struggling for quite a while, I created another user on my machine with no special characters and everything works fine now.

Answer (score 2):

First, enter the command:
`gem environment gemdir`
Then `cd` to the directory shown. `cd` to the sub-directory `bin` and find the full path to `bin`. Then add this to your PATH.

Comment: Ok that helped, but now I'm getting `C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in 'require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)`

Comment: I think that the fix for this to add this at the start of your script, before you require anything: `$LOAD_PATH<<(%x[gem environment gemdir]+"lib")`. If you are running rails from the command line, I'm not sure.

Comment: on windows 7 this is what gem enviorment gemdir gives me :

"C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby2.2.0\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0" 
what now ? i can't figure out what to add to my path.

Answer (score 1):

I was installing `rubyinstaller-2.1.7-x64.exe`

Search for file `railties-4.2.5.gem`, on my pc it is located in `c:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\cache\railties-4.2.5.gem`

Type:

```
gem install c:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\cache\railties-4.2.5.gem --local
```

And try to call : `rails -v`
It is should working and show **Rails 4.2.5**